# Length of a word

Tags: dictionary

Probably my problem is very simple but I couldn't have found a solution to it anywhere else.

How can I find a word of a certain length using a [`DictionaryLookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DictionaryLookup.html) function? What things stand for a universal single letter?

I appreciate your help in resolving that problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may find some help in the documentation for [string patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StringPatterns.html): `_` is the universal placeholder you seek, so we can construct an appropriate pattern for handing to `DictionaryLookup`:

```
dl[len_]:=DictionaryLookup[Repeated[_, {len}]]
```

(meaning: "there must be exactly `len` arbitrary characters in the string").

Example:

```
dl[20]
(* {"Andrianampoinimerina", "buckminsterfullerene", 
    "compartmentalization", "counterrevolutionary", 
    "electroencephalogram", "great-granddaughters", 
    "institutionalization", "internationalization", 
    "magnetohydrodynamics", "uncharacteristically"} *)
```

Timings:

```
AbsoluteTiming[dl[20]][[1]]
(* 0.020801 *)
AbsoluteTiming[DictionaryLookup[a__ /; StringLength[a] == 20]][[1]]
(* 0.608601 *)
```

So, if you also need speed, `dl` might be preferable.

Comment: `StartOfString` and `EndOfString` are superfluous, `DictionaryLookup@Repeated[_, {5}]` is enough.

Comment: @Pickett: Thanks. I'll update.

Answer (score 5):

```
DictionaryLookup[a__ /; StringLength[a] == 5]
```

`Blank` (`_`) stands for a single letter. `__` stands for one or more letters. `___` stands for zero or more letters. `a_`, `a__` or `a___` give the matching string the name `a` and `/; StringLength[a] == 5` imposes a condition on the pattern which says that "this pattern only matches when `a` is five characters long."